# What is the difference between scikitkearn label encoder and the older categorical encoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, label-encoding

Before label encoder was added into scikit learn, there was a thing called the categorical encoder, but I do not know the difference between the two, as they both seem to do the same thing, while LabelEncoded seems to be a new name for CagoricalEncoder. Is this accurate? Also, what is the difference between these two and the LabelBinarizer, as all seem to have the same purpose to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like by this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155094/categorical-encoder-in-scikit-learn-preprocessing), Categorical encoder was replaced by Label encoder.
About Label Binarizer and Label Encoder, you can look here: [StackOverflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473381/scikit-learns-labelbinarizer-vs-onehotencoder)